# OrderBy has stopped working for LINQ Queries in Mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am surprised to see that ordering by date is not working properly no matter what I try on the latest C# driver. Pretty sure this was working before.

Here are some examples where dates are not ordered properly and coming out of sequence:

```
var row = mongoCollection.AsQueryable<EntityClass>()
          .OrderBy(p => p.MyDateTime.Value)
          .OrderBy(p => p.OtherId).Where(p => p.MyId == myData.MyId)
          .FirstOrDefault();

var row = (from p in mongoCollection.AsQueryable<EntityClass>()
          where p.MyId == myData.MyId
          orderby p.MyDateTime.Value ascending
          orderby p.OtherId ascending
          select p)
          .FirstOrDefault();

row = (from p in mongoCollection.AsQueryable<EntityClass>()
       where p.MyId == myData.MyId &&
           p.OtherId > row.OtherId
       orderby p.MyDateTime.Value ascending
       orderby p.OtherId ascending
       select p)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

None of these work. I get dates out of sequence. I even tried adding an index on the date column in the server - made no difference.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: In method syntax, use `ThenBy`. In query syntax, use single `order by a, b, c...`. Currently only the last order by is in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's answer works. Separate add multiple columns in the same orderby. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please delete it and add this as a comment or edit to your question.  Then delete this answer.